# Meaning of this sentence "if you want to glimpse the future, just look behind you"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence

I was going through the [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=furious-7) of the motion picture Furious 7 and in the opening scene Jason Statham says:

> *If you want to glimpse the future, just look behind you*

Before posting this question, I did some research over the internet to figure out some other occasions where this sentence may have been used, but most of the results that I got are related to this dialogue from this movie.

So I'm a bit confused by what he means by "***look behind you***". Is he saying that our future will be similar to our past?

Comment: Interpretation requests (in fact, all criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature) are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is not an interpretation request. This question simply is asking for the meaning in context. Moreover, the Help Center too suggests that questions related to **word choice & usage** & **dialects** can be asked. Nonetheless, I have edited the question hoping that it fits the rules better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like another way of saying that "history repeats itself" which could be the case for the Furious movies. However, I think in the way that it is stated in this movie it is a way of saying that every part of your past is a piece of your future and if you were to analyze the makeup of your past you may begin to know what your future holds.

If this is true then one could look at life much like a math equation. If you want to know the answer you first have to know all the pieces of the problem. It's like A + B + C + D + E = F where F is your future and A-E are all the pieces making up your past. You could never be an astronaut in your future if you didn't have some sort of training making up your past.

Finally, in the movie context you could say that if you have really paid attention to the previous six movies, then you may have some idea what the future holds for these characters in the seventh movie. These past events have been leading up to something and Jason Statham's character may be eluding to this being a culminating chapter to the saga.

Answer (score 3):

Context is everything, [full quote as per imdb](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2820852/quotes?qt=qt2453145):

> Deckard Shaw: [first lines, speaking to comatose Owen Shaw] They say if you want to glimpse the future, just look behind you. I used to think that was bollocks. And now I realise you can't outrun the past. When we were kids, you started fights with the toughest bastards in the yard, and I was the one that to step in and finish them. Rest now, little brother, want to settle you one last score.

Pretty self-explanatory, they put the explanation right behind your sentence. It's a case of history repeats itself.